# How exclude ITEMs when condition is... XSLT

Tags: xslt, transform, nodes

I have following XML.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ordersPack id="1398720518" ic="12345678" application="Web" version="2.0" note="user">

    <orderPackItem id="2014042847">
        <order>
            <orderHeader>
                <numberOrder>2014042847</numberOrder>

                <partnerIdentity>
                    <billing>
                        <firstname>Ilona</firstname>
                        <surname>Kokerková</surname>
                        </billing>
                    </partnerIdentity>
                </orderHeader>
            <orderDetail>
                <orderItem>
                    <name><![CDATA[Kokosový panenský olej 1000 ml]]></name>
                    <unitPriceWithTax>290.00</unitPriceWithTax>
                    </orderItem>
                <orderItem>
                    <name><![CDATA[Dobírka ČP - Balík na poštu]]></name>
                    <quantity>1</quantity>
                    <percentVAT>21</percentVAT>
                    <unitPrice>86.78</unitPrice>
                    <unitPriceWithTax>105.00</unitPriceWithTax>
                    </orderItem>
                </orderDetail>
            <orderSummary>
                </orderSummary>
            </order>
        </orderPackItem>

    <orderPackItem id="2014042846">
        <order>
            <orderHeader>
                <orderType>receivedOrder</orderType>
                <partnerIdentity>
                    <billing>
                        <firstname>David</firstname>
                        <surname>Liala</surname>
                        </billing>
                    </partnerIdentity>
                </orderHeader>
            <orderDetail>
                <orderItem>
                    <name><![CDATA[Mikula Bio Mladý ječmen prášek 250 g]]></name>
                    <unitPriceWithTax>469.00</unitPriceWithTax>
                    </orderItem>
                <orderItem>
                    <name><![CDATA[osobní odběr Brno, Orlí 16, AWA centrum]]></name>
                    <unitPriceWithTax>0.00</unitPriceWithTax>
                    </orderItem>
                </orderDetail>
            <orderSummary>
                </orderSummary>
            </order>
        </orderPackItem>
    </ordersPack>
```

I need exclude all items with  `<dat:dataPackItem>` if `<inv:text>Hotově, osobní odběr</inv:text>` contain "Hotově, osobní odběr".

And desire output is :

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="windows-1250"?>
    <dat:dataPack id="fa002" ico="12345678" application="StwTest" version="2.0" note="FA" ">

        <dat:dataPackItem id="2014042847" version="2.0">
            <inv:invoice version="2.0">
                <inv:invoiceHeader>
                    <inv:invoiceType>issuedInvoice</inv:invoiceType>
                    </inv:accounting>
                    <inv:classificationVAT>
                        <typ:ids>UD</typ:ids>
                        </inv:classificationVAT>
                    <inv:partnerIdentity>
                        <typ:address>
                            <typ:company>firma</typ:company>
                            <typ:division>Obchodní oddělení</typ:division>
                            <typ:name>IlonaKokerková</typ:name>
                            </typ:address>
                        </inv:partnerIdentity>
                    <inv:paymentType>
                        <typ:paymentType>delivery</typ:paymentType>
                        </inv:paymentType>
                    <inv:account>
                        <typ:ids>KB</typ:ids>
                        </inv:account>
                    <inv:intNote>Faktura s textovou a skladovou položkou</inv:intNote>
                    </inv:invoiceHeader>
                <inv:invoiceDetail>
                    <inv:invoiceItem>
                        <inv:text>Kokosový panenský olej 1000 ml</inv:text>
                        <inv:homeCurrency>
                            <typ:unitPrice>290.00</typ:unitPrice>
                            </inv:homeCurrency>
                        <inv:stockItem>
                            <typ:stockItem>
                                <typ:ids>awa1265</typ:ids>
                                </typ:stockItem>
                            </inv:stockItem>
                        </inv:invoiceItem>
                    <inv:invoiceItem>
                        <inv:text>Dobírka zboží</inv:text>
                        <inv:homeCurrency>
                            <typ:unitPrice>0.00</typ:unitPrice>
                            </inv:homeCurrency>
                        <inv:stockItem>
                            <typ:stockItem>
                                <typ:ids></typ:ids>
                                </typ:stockItem>
                            </inv:stockItem>
                        </inv:invoiceItem>
                    <inv:invoiceItem>
                        <inv:text>Dobírka ČP - Balík na poštu</inv:text>
                        <inv:homeCurrency>
                            <typ:unitPrice>105.00</typ:unitPrice>
                            </inv:homeCurrency>
                        <inv:stockItem>
                            <typ:stockItem>
                                <typ:ids></typ:ids>
                                </typ:stockItem>
                            </inv:stockItem>
                        </inv:invoiceItem>
                    </inv:invoiceDetail>
                </inv:invoice>
            </dat:dataPackItem>
        </dat:dataPack>
```

I need exclude all items with  `<dat:dataPackItem>` if `<inv:text>Hotově, osobní odběr</inv:text>` contain "Hotově, osobní odběr".

How to do it?

Here is my XSLT....

```
        <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
        <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" >
            <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" encoding="windows-1250" />

            <xsl:template match="/">  
                <dat:dataPack id="fa002" ico="12345678" application="StwTest" version = "2.0" note="Import FA">
                    <xsl:for-each select="ordersPack/orderPackItem">
                        <dat:dataPackItem id="{order/orderHeader/numberOrder}" version="2.0">
                            <!-- faktura bez adresy s textovou a skladovou polozkou-->
                            <inv:invoice version="2.0">
                                <inv:invoiceHeader>


                                    <inv:symVar>
                                        <xsl:value-of select="order/orderHeader/numberOrder"/>
                                        </inv:symVar>


                                    <inv:numberOrder>
                                        <xsl:value-of select="order/orderHeader/numberOrder"/>
                                        </inv:numberOrder>
                                    <inv:dateOrder>
                                        <xsl:value-of select="order/orderHeader/dateFrom"/>
                                        </inv:dateOrder>
                                    <inv:partnerIdentity>

                                        <typ:address>

                                            <typ:company>firma</typ:company>
                                            <typ:division>Obchodní oddělení</typ:division>
                                            <typ:name>
                                                <xsl:value-of select="order/orderHeader/partnerIdentity/billing/firstname"/>
                                                <xsl:value-of select="order/orderHeader/partnerIdentity/billing/surname"/>
                                                </typ:name>

                                            </typ:address>

                                        </inv:partnerIdentity>
                                    <inv:paymentType>
                                        <typ:paymentType>
                                            <xsl:choose><xsl:when test="order/orderDetail/orderItem/name='Dobírka zboží'">delivery</xsl:when>
                                                <xsl:otherwise>draft</xsl:otherwise></xsl:choose>  
                                            </typ:paymentType>
                                        </inv:paymentType>
                                    <inv:account>                   
                                        <typ:ids>KB</typ:ids>
                                        </inv:account>
                                    <inv:note>Načteno z XML</inv:note>
                                    <inv:intNote>Faktura s textovou a skladovou položkou</inv:intNote>
                                    </inv:invoiceHeader>
                                <inv:invoiceDetail>       
                                    <!--skladova polozka-->
                                    <xsl:for-each select="order/orderDetail/orderItem">
                                        <inv:invoiceItem>
                                            <inv:text>
                                                <xsl:value-of select="name"/>
                                                </inv:text>
                                            <inv:quantity>
                                                <xsl:value-of select="quantity"/>
                                                </inv:quantity>
                                            <inv:payVAT>true</inv:payVAT>
                                            <xsl:choose>
                                                <xsl:when test="percentVAT = '15'">
                                                    <inv:rateVAT>low</inv:rateVAT>
                                                    </xsl:when>
                                                <xsl:when test="percentVAT = '21'">
                                                    <inv:rateVAT>high</inv:rateVAT>
                                                    </xsl:when>
                                                </xsl:choose>     
                                            <inv:homeCurrency>           
                                                <typ:unitPrice>
                                                    <xsl:value-of select="unitPriceWithTax"/>
                                                    </typ:unitPrice>
                                                </inv:homeCurrency>
                                            <inv:stockItem>
                                                <typ:stockItem>
                                                    <typ:ids>
                                                        <xsl:value-of select="product_nr"/>
                                                        </typ:ids>
                                                    </typ:stockItem>
                                                </inv:stockItem>
                                            </inv:invoiceItem>
                                        </xsl:for-each>
                                    </inv:invoiceDetail>

                                </inv:invoice>
                            </dat:dataPackItem>
                        </xsl:for-each>
                    </dat:dataPack>      
                </xsl:template>
            </xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to think in terms of the *input*, not the *output*.  If you want to exclude all `orderItem` elements whose `name` includes "Hotově, osobní odběr" then you need to add a predicate to the `orderItem` `for-each`:

```
<!--skladova polozka-->
<xsl:for-each select="order/orderDetail/orderItem[not(contains(name, 'Hotově, osobní odběr'))]">
```

To completely remove any `orderPackItem` that contains any `orderItem` with this text you need the predicate at the top level:

```
<xsl:for-each select="ordersPack/orderPackItem[
        not(order/orderDetail/orderItem[
             contains(name, 'Hotově, osobní odběr')])]">
```